# Are database diagrams needed in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I used SQL Server Migration Assistant to transfer and link Access tables. I was surprised that I did not have to do much after the migration. My Access front end was working perfectly fine as if nothing was changed. However, I saw that the database diagrams in SQL Server and Relationships in my Access front end were both missing.

How is it that removing the relationships made no difference to the outcome. Are relationships just for visual reference for the developers?

Comment: Relationships are used to enforce referential integrity. Now you just won't notice if one records references another which doesn't exist whereas before that wasn't possible.

Comment: Are you saying your diagrams are gone, or your foreign keys themselves are gone?

Comment: This is probably off topic for Stack Overflow, better to be posted on [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com). There is far more to relationships that the visual representation of them in a diagram. In fact, the diagram is very likely the lowest concern; especially considering that diagrams were deprecated in SSMS, and are removed in the next version (currently in preview).

Comment: My foreign keys and constraints are still there as I can see it in my SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Okay so if your foreign keys and constraints are still there then you're likely to just need to enable database diagrams and then you should be able to see those relationships.

Comment: The yes/no answer is no: database diagrams are not needed. They can be useful to some people, but they are just a visual representation. You don't need a speedometer to drive fast. :-